# How did the solver get rid of the minus?

Tags: calculus

I can't seem to understand how the solver managed to get rid of the minus.
Can someone enlighten me please?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the full argument (which I imagine is by induction on the number of square root signs), it is probably $\sqrt{a-b}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{\sqrt{a+b}}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$.

Comment: That is probably the key to solving this expression, however I fail to understand how we ended up without any minuses.

Comment: If you expand that out and simplify it, you get the left-hand side again in the numerator but with one fewer square root sign.  I suspect they substituted in an induction hypothesis from there.

Answer (score 2):

Define $s_0=0,\;s_n=\sqrt{2+s_{n-1}}\;.$ We have $s_1=\sqrt2,\;s_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2},\;$ and so on. We want to prove $\sqrt{2-s_n}=2/\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} s_k\;$
for all $n\ge0$ by induction. But $\;\sqrt{2-s_0}=\sqrt{2}=2/s_1,\;$ and $\sqrt{2-s_n}s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2-s_{n-1}}\;$ since $\;(2-s_n)(2+s_n)=4-s_n^2=4-(2+s_{n-1})=2-s_{n-1}.$

By the way, $\;2^{n+1}\sqrt{2-s_n}\to\pi\;$ as $\;n\to\infty.$